# C# : Trying to call a UserControl function from another Form

Tags: c#, user-controls, public, void

My problem is simple. I wish to click button1 which is placed upon Form1 and see the backcolor of UserControl1 which is placed upon Form2 change to red. Obviously this result is not met. I'm a novice to C# so take this into consideration greatly when answering the question. In advance, thank you for your help.

Code for Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserControlAccessTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            userControl1.UserControlColorChange();

        }
    }
}
```

Code for Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserControlAccessTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Code for UserControl1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserControlAccessTest
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UserControlColorChange()
        {
            UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
            userControl1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to the actual instance of UserControl1 that's on form2 (Assuming you have one).
Try this:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
form2.userControl1.UserControlColorChange();
```

Comment: Sorry. Where is this code meant to be placed? I wasn't quite sure.

Comment: in form1, in button1_Click event handler.

Comment: Tried this. The button opens the second form however the userControl backcolor remains the same.

To be clear. I have a usercontrol named userControl1 placed upon Form2 in design view. I have the modifier set to public. Is there anything I could have done wrong here?

Comment: Well, now I see that the method called UserControlColorChange() needs a change also. replace it's content with this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

Comment: You sir, are my hero.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark this answer as accepted so that other people will know this issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

FORM1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserControlAccessTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        form2.changeColor();
    }
}
}
```

FORM2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserControlAccessTest
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void changeColor()
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't wish to be rude. But I don't think you read the entire question.